# Is it possible to filter an NSArray by class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nspredicate

Is there a way construct a predicate to filter by class type?

I currently loop through the array and check to the class of each object. Maybe there is a cleaner way?

Comment: Why are you putting such different objects into the same array in the first place?

Comment: One reason is if you have an array of abstract classes. You may have all Person classes, but you want to filter out Doctors or Lawyers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could add a category to NSObject that adds a "cf_className" method, like so:

```
@interface NSObject (CFAdditions)
- (NSString *) cf_className;
@end

@implementation NSObject (CFAdditions)
- (NSString *) cf_className {
  return NSStringFromClass([self class]);
}
@end
```

From there, you can use predicates like:

```
NSPredicate * p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cf_className = %@", aClass];
NSArray * filtered = [anArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

If you're on the Mac, you can just use `-[NSObject className]` instead of having to create the category.  The iPhone doesn't have that method, hence the need for a category.

Comment: You can also do self.class.description

Answer (score 78):

You can directly compare classes as well in your predicate.

But, it probably won't work as you would expect if you're trying to filter for objects that belong to class clusters or if you have subclasses.

For example, `NSDate` when instantiated is usually an `__NSCFDate` and `NSString` can be `NSCFString` as well as other specific private classes.

It's probably better to just loop through the set yourself and use `-isKindOfClass:` as the test.

**IF** you *really* want to use `NSPredicate` though you can do this. As an example, this would filter an array for all objects derived from `NSString`. If you wanted strict class membership you could replace `isKindOfClass:` with `isMemberOfClass:`.

Any selector that all objects in the collection implement, takes one argument and returns a `BOOL` should work though.

```
NSArray *mixedArray = {...};
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                      @"self isKindOfClass: %@",
                                      [NSString class]];

NSLog(@"%@", [mixedArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

Comment: +1 I've never thought of putting the selector directly in the predicate.  Neat!

Comment: It's not mentioned in the Predicate Programming Guide (which means doing this in a format string is technically undocumented), but the custom-selector feature is backed up by the reference: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSComparisonPredicate_Class/Reference/NSComparisonPredicate.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSComparisonPredicate/predicateWithLeftExpression:rightExpression:customSelector: Very cool.

Comment: Yeah, I originally had it written the long way but on a lark tried it in the format string and was surprised to see it work.

Comment: The reason why is discouraged is that the predicate translate this to other kinds of predicate statements (like in Core Data by translating it to a SQL statement).

Comment: @AshleyClark what's the long way?

Comment: @ZacBowling is there an encouraged way to do this? Will this work with Core Data? I have a `linkedAccounts` to-many relationship and want to find the one that is of class `FacebookAccount`.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale With core data? It's better to enumerate the NSEntityDescription's attributes and check for NSRelationshipAttribute objects. Then cast and check "isToMany" and the "destinationEntity" properties. If you need more details, ask another question so I can post some sample code and get some loved karama.

Comment: @ZacBowling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984820/core-data-nspredicate-filter-by-entity-class

Answer (score 29):

Starting in iOS 4 and Mac OS 10.6, one can use `+[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]` as well. For example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
}];
```

This allows you to express your predicates purely in Objective-C rather than the predicate syntax required by `predicateWithFormat:`.