# NSPredicate check for kind of object class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nspredicate

I have an array of `UIView` objects. I want to call `- (NSArray *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` on this array to get array of `MyCustomView` objects.

How to code predicate with "isKindOf:"?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try (**depracated**)

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"className == %@", [someObject className]]
```

Or

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"class == %@", [someObject class]]
```

Comment: Works with `className` too for me. Though `class` looks cleaner.

Comment: What is more appropriate? "=" or "LIKE"?

Comment: When using like, `?` and `*` can be used as wildcard characters. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Comment: Surely this predicate would be the equivalent of `isMemberOfClass:`, not `isKindOfClass:` as per the original question?

Comment: I haven't tested this but you could always call `super` in the predicate and compare to that.

Comment: As @Tommy says, this is not the right answer to the question as stated.  The right answer is given below by zekel.

Comment: Right, this would be isMemberOfClass, rather than isKindOfClass.  That said, I'm glad this answer is here, because using className could be the only workable solution if the class isn't actually available (e.g. cross-process calls).  So thanks for that answer.

Answer (score 30):

I got errors using Jef's method. This worked for me, though.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                              @"self isKindOfClass: %@", class];
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556306/168594

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is the Swift version of Jef's Method:

```
NSPredicate(format: "className = %@", String(describing: MyCustomView.self))
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using `-className` as your key?

```
NSPredicate* foo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"className == %@", @"MyCustomView"];
```