# NSPredicate that filters out subclass results

Tags: ios, ios5, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have two classes, Company and MyCompany. MyCompany is a subclass of Company, and Company is a subclass of NSManagedObject. I am trying to write a predicate for an NSFetchRequest that will return results of the class Company, but filter out MyCompany objects.

I have tried the following (suggested from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065935/472344):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"class != %@",NSStringFromClass([myCompany class])];
```

But I get an error:

```
'keypath class not found in entity <NSSQLEntity CKCompany id=1>'
```

I also tried (suggested from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11693983/472344, I know I really want not SELF isKindOfClass, but I was just testing with the exact same command as given in the answer):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [myCompany class];
```

And got the following error:

```
'Unknown/unsupported comparison predicate operator type'
```

How can I write a predicate to achieve what I want? I am supporting iOS 5 and above.

Comment: The class in question is not an NSObject so it doesn't respond to "class" or "className"

Comment: Company and MyCompany are NSObjects as as they inherit from NSManagedObject, but I realize now that the predicate is being applied to the NSSQLEntity and so my situation is not equivalent to the situation those answers were responding to. However I still need a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set

```
[fetchRequest setIncludesSubentities:NO];
```

so that the fetch request returns only objects of exactly the entity type of the request,
and does not include subentities.

It is (as far as I know) not possible to refer to the objects class or entity name in a predicate if the predicate is used in a Core Data fetch request.

Comment: That sounds like it will work, and thanks for the extra information. I will try this.