# Swift 3: Use NSPredicate(format:) to filter objects by type/class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nspredicate

I got stuck with a problem regarding the NSPredicate syntax. I want to filter an array of objects by their class types.

```
class ClassA: NSObject {}
class ClassB: ClassA {}
class ClassC: ClassA {}

let array: [ClassA] = [ClassB(), ClassC()]
```

Now I want to use an NSPredicate to get a filtered array only with ClassB items.

I could use Blocks to do so, and it would be something like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate { (object, nil) -> Bool in
    return object is ClassB
}
```

Although this is a legitimate approach, I also want to do the exact same thing with NSPredicate(format:).

Among other attempts I unsuccessfully tried the following:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self = %@", [ClassB.self])
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF isKindOfClass: %@", [ClassB.self])
```

I think it must be just a syntax problem, but I'm looking for over an hour to solve this with no result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not the native Swift way `array.filter{ $0 is ClassB }` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8065866/2557145

Comment: @vadian I want to create more complex and dynamic compound-predicates

Comment: You can do that with Swift functions, too.

Comment: @Palle I tried `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "class == %@", [ClassB.self])` with no result. I think it is not a duplicate, because I'm looking for the swift 3 counterpart.

Comment: @stoikr You don't need square parentheses. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19289687/1187415

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "class = %@", ClassB.self)
```

Here is a documentation page about predicates - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-CJBDBHCB

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I do this, I get the error "Argument type 'ClassB.Type' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'"

Comment: @stoikr are you sure that ClassA is subclassed from the NSObject?

Comment: In my code base it is in fact an NSManagedObject, which is a subclass of NSObject

Comment: @stoikr try to add explicit cast to CVarArg - ClassB.self as CVarArg.