# Searching for particular MKAnnotation class in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, filter, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have 4-5 kinds of different annotations classes in mapView.
 With following code I expect only  AnnotationType1 should respond to for loop.

```
for (AnnotationType1* annotation in mymap.annotations) 
        {
NSLog(@"annotation class is %@", [annotation class]);
}
```

But as is evident from console I get other classes also.

```
annotation class is AnnotationType1
annotation class is AnnotationType2
annotation class is AnnotationType3
annotation class is AnnotationType4
```

what will be the best way to perform actions only on say AnnotationType1 annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as you've discovered, fast iteration doesn't work the way you thought it did. `mymap.annotations` returns the same array of annotation objects no matter what -- it doesn't have any idea what kind of pointer you're assigning them to.

Second, it's usually considered a bad idea to count on a view (such as MKMapView) to store data (like your annotations). It's fine for the map view to *know about* the annotations -- it must know about them to do its job properly. But I wouldn't recommend counting on the map view to maintain the app's state. You probably have the annotation objects stored somewhere in your data model -- if so, that'd be a better place to get the list of annotations.

Third, you can filter the array using a predicate. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2555082/643383) for help using a predicate to filter by class name.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Caleb. That was very useful. I will have separate arrays for storing different kinds of annotation types.