# Core Data NSPredicate filter by entity class?

Tags: class, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, nsentitydescription

How would I create an `NSPredicate` to filter by entity of class `Contact`?

The solution to [NSPredicate check for kind of object class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8065935/242933) crashes:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person.class == %@", [Contact class]];

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: 'keypath person.class not found in entity <NSSQLEntity User id=12>'
```

#### Background

I have the Core Data entities `User` (app user) & `Contact` (address book contact), both children of `Person` (abstract entity). `Person` has many `identities`, which can be `emails`, `phones`, or `usernames`.

To create a text-message-like typeahead, I want to create an `NSFetchRequest` for `Identity` entities where `person` is of class `Contact`.

Comment: COuld you provide an screenshot of your datamodel?Maybe i'll be able to help then.

Answer (score 2):

You are perhaps mixing up a few things. The answer you indicate is about a predicate to filter an array of `UIView`s. A predicate in core data works in a slightly different way.

To achieve your desired result, simply set the `entity` of your fetch request to `@"Contact"`.

Comment: I would, but I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, and I want each row of the table to be an `Identity` (email or phone). Create a new text message on your iPhone and start typing in the to-field to see what I mean. Each row of the typeahead table is an `email` or `phone`, not a `Contact`. I.e., if you have a `Contact` with one `email` and one `phone`, he'll show up twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a required field in Contact, you can filter on that field being not null. If you don't have a required field in Contact (that is not in Person), you could add a dummy required field and filter on that field.