# Brand New project View Controller has 2 "hidden" buttons on it

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uibutton

I am running this code, because I want to change something on all the buttons within my `ViewController` when it starts.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    int i = 1;
    
    for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"Count I - %d ", i);
        //NSLog(@"Count I - %d - %@", i, btn.titleLabel.text);
        
        i++;
    }
}
```

The Output it:

> 2013-11-11 08:15:13.315 testingSingle[7876:a0b] Count I - 1
>
> 2013-11-11 08:15:13.317 testingSingle[7876:a0b] Count I - 2

Now this seems strange to me, because it is a new project and nothing has been dragged onto or even changed on the VC in the storyboard or in code - there is nothing to suggest that there 2 `UIButton`s.

How can I get this message to `return 0` if this is the case? My app crashes because of this.

Comment: What makes you think that all the subviews are UIButtons?

Comment: oh I thought that I asking for that - mmm ok learned something new :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your NSLog to

```
NSLog(@"%@", [btn class]);
```

gives the output

```
_UILayoutGuide 
_UILayoutGuide
```

which shows that there are no buttons, but some other views (perhaps required for Autolayout).

```
for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
```

enumerates *all* subviews, it does not matter that the loop variable `btw` is 
declared as `UIButton *`.
To handle only buttons, you have to test the class of each object:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)subView;
        // Do something with btn ...
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: If one wished to have an array of buttons in general, `-[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]` and an [`NSPredicate` testing class membership](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554894/is-it-possible-to-filter-an-nsarray-by-class/19894246) could also be used.